# decoding ascii characters in php

Tags: php, ascii, decode

Some uploaded image path was stored in my database with some `ASCII` characters as so

```
Capture+d%E2%80%99e%CC%81cran+2014-08-15+a%CC%80+13.36.06.png
```

I tried to decode it using `urldecode`, `icon`, `htmlspecialchars_decode`, `mb_convert_encoding`, but I can't get my true file name

```
Capture d’écran 2014-08-15 à 13.36.06.png
```

How can it be ?

Edit using `url decode` outputs this

```
Capture dâ€™eÌcran 2014-08-15 aÌ€ 13.36.06.png
```

`html_entity_decode` outputs this

```
Capture+d%E2%80%99e%CC%81cran+2014-08-15+a%CC%80+13.36.06.png
```

Comment: That's why you replace file names with random strings!

Comment: @Justinas Better not random strings, but time followed by (for instance) the user id.

Comment: `urldecode()` worked for me, can you edit to include the code you're using? There's probably a bug in that. 
Oh, and try using `<meta charset="utf-8">` on your page. `urldecode()` didn't work properly until I did that.

Comment: @wumm same meaning as random string, i think

Comment: @AgentTadpole I have updated my post. Sure I have set `<meta charset="utf-8">` in my page ;)

Comment: @Justinas I have just edited my post. This is what `urldecode` outputs

Comment: @user1611830 That's the exact output I got when I didn't use `<meta charset="utf-8">` on my page. Once I added that, it worked. [Here's a link](http://pastebin.com/tgzTJ2Sz) to the exact code that works for me, let me know if it doesn't work on your setup.

Comment: @AgentTadpole I have just checked in ly console, I do have `<meta charset="utf-8">` in my page !

Comment: @user1611830 Can you put all the code of your page onto pastebin so I can see what's going wrong?

Comment: Maybe try adjusting to web rule no. 1: Never use spaces and special chars in file names. :)

Comment: Side note: can't you just use that file name as is, without messing with it? For future, just rename files you save to server

Comment: you can't check on console!!!. if you see a wired sequence of chars, that means that the console, can't handle UTF there. but the wired sequence of bytes (shown as chars) that you see is correct to any one that can interpret UTF (in example, the Browser when proper meta or header was sent to it).  As an extra test, you can redirect the output of PHP execution to a file, then open that file with an editor that handles UTF and you will see what you expect.